# Issue when saving Spark dataframe to ArangoDB using the Arango-Spark connector

Tags: apache-spark, arangodb

I am trying to save a Spark dataframe into ArangoDB yet I have encountered a few issues:

1. The data (vertices) saved into Arango includes a lot of unneeded “schema” information about the records
2. The more critical issue is that the save operation ignore my “_key” fields and generates random keys instead

Here is a code snippet

```
import com.arangodb.spark.{ArangoSpark, WriteOptions}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession   
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf}

object TestGraph extends App{
  println("Hello, test!")

  // set up Spark
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MySparkDriverApp").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  // set arango options and save vertices
  var options = new WriteOptions()
  options = options.database("test")
  options = options.user("root")
  options = options.password("openSesame")

  val rdd_v = sc.parallelize(Seq(("v1","a"),("v2","b")))
  val df_v = spark.createDataFrame(rdd_v).toDF("_key", "f1")
  df_v.show()

  ArangoSpark.save(df_v, "test_vertex", options)

  println("Test completed")
}
```

Here is how the data looks in ArangoDB (queried via the REST API)

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "_key": "8607",
            "_id": "test_vertex/8607",
            "_rev": "_Wq0DOVS--_",
            "schema": {
                "_hashCode": 1762032556,
                "bitmap$0": 8,
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "dataType": {
                            "ordering": {
                                "evidence$1$1": {}
                            }
                        },
                        "metadata": {
                            "_hashCode": -1609326920,
                            "bitmap$0": true,
                            "map": {}
                        },
                        "name": "_key",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    {
                        "dataType": {
                            "ordering": {
                                "evidence$1$1": {}
                            }
                        },
                        "metadata": {
                            "_hashCode": -1609326920,
                            "bitmap$0": true,
                            "map": {}
                        },
                        "name": "f1",
                        "nullable": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            "values": [
                "v2",
                "b"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_key": "8613",
            "_id": "test_vertex/8613",
            "_rev": "_Wq0DOVW--_",
            "schema": {
                "_hashCode": 1762032556,
                "bitmap$0": 8,
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "dataType": {
                            "ordering": {
                                "evidence$1$1": {}
                            }
                        },
                        "metadata": {
                            "_hashCode": -1609326920,
                            "bitmap$0": true,
                            "map": {}
                        },
                        "name": "_key",
                        "nullable": true
                    },
                    {
                        "dataType": {
                            "ordering": {
                                "evidence$1$1": {}
                            }
                        },
                        "metadata": {
                            "_hashCode": -1609326920,
                            "bitmap$0": true,
                            "map": {}
                        },
                        "name": "f1",
                        "nullable": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            "values": [
                "v1",
                "a"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "hasMore": false,
    "count": 2,
    "cached": false,
    "extra": {
        "stats": {
            "writesExecuted": 0,
            "writesIgnored": 0,
            "scannedFull": 2,
            "scannedIndex": 0,
            "filtered": 0,
            "httpRequests": 0,
            "executionTime": 0.00011944770812988281
        },
        "warnings": []
    },
    "error": false,
    "code": 201
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When saving a `DataFrame` you have to use the method

```
ArangoSpark.saveDF(DataFrame, String, WriteOptions)
```

instead of

```
ArangoSpark.save(Dataset, String, WriteOptions)
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help either. Looks like it is simply another wrapper to the same method "saveRDD". I ended up writing my own class using the ArangoDB Java Driver https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver

Comment: This is strange. I used your example code and changed the method to `saveDF` and it worked for me. It is of course valid to save your data directly with the java driver but then you don't use the Spark partitioning mechanic the ArangoDB Spark connector is using, which results in performance loss when you work with a lot of data in a ArangoDB cluster setup.